# Why converting numpy.ndarray to custom data type using numpy.ndarray.astype multiplies my data?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, type-conversion, custom-data-type

Executing this code:

```
import numpy as np

py_list = [2013, 8, 0.6552562894775783]
custom_type = np.dtype([
                        ('YEAR',np.uint16),
                        ('DOY', np.uint16),
                        ('REF',np.float16)
                        ])

NumPy_array = np.array(py_list)
NumPy_array_converted = NumPy_array.astype(custom_type)

print 'custom_type is:'
print custom_type
print '---------------------------------------------'
print 'py_list is:'
print py_list
print '---------------------------------------------'
print 'NumPy_array is:'
print NumPy_array
print '---------------------------------------------'
print 'NumPy_array converted to custom_type is:'
print NumPy_array_converted
print '---------------------------------------------'
```

Prints:

```
custom_type is:
[('YEAR', '<u2'), ('DOY', '<u2'), ('REF', '<f2')]
---------------------------------------------
py_list is:
[2013, 8, 0.6552562894775783]
---------------------------------------------
NumPy_array is:
[  2.01300000e+03   8.00000000e+00   6.55256289e-01]
---------------------------------------------
NumPy_array converted to custom_type is:
[(2013, 2013, 2013.0) (8, 8, 8.0) (0, 0, 0.6552734375)]
---------------------------------------------
```

**1) The question is why after convertion to custom data type my data is tripled `NumPy_array_converted` in comparison with not converted numpy array `NumPy_array`?**

**2) How to change `custom_type` to get not trippled array?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
np.array([tuple(py_list)], custom_type)
```

produces

```
array([(2013, 8, 0.6552734375)], 
  dtype=[('YEAR', '<u2'), ('DOY', '<u2'), ('REF', '<f2')])
```

Data for structured arrays are supposed to a list of tuples (orjust one tuple).  Notice how the values are displayed. `[(...)]`.

There may be a way of doing this with `astype`, but it is tricky.

Also,notice what `NumPy_array` is - 3 floats, while `py_list` is 2 ints and a float.  And `custom_type` wants to convert those 2 ints to 'u2'.  They aren't compatible.

Comment: Those 2 integers are year (values 1900 - 2100) and day of the year (values 1 - 366) so "u2" is ok for them.

Comment: You method works fine. But I get round brackets in my list: [(2013, 8, 0.6552734375)] Can I somehow get rid of them?

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of them?  That is how numpy displays a custom type like yours.  Think of it as a record.

Comment: It's the floats that aren't compatible with `u2` - 4 bytes v 2.

Comment: Because it gives me more dimensions in my array. To acess `NumPy_array` values I can write `NumPy_array[0]`. To acess the same value in `NumPy_array_converted` with round brackets i have to write one more square brackets `NumPy_array_converted[0][0]`

Comment: I assume this is just the start of constructing an array with many more triplets of data like this.  You aren't just trying to put names on three numbers in a list.